# "$f$ is monotonic, so there exists an open sub-interval on which f is constant."

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on some questions on real analysis and was hoping to get some help regarding my thoughts on these two questions so far:

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$

"$f$ is monotonic (not strictly), so there exists an open sub-interval on which f is constant."

As $f$ is not strictly monotonic, every $f(x)\geq f(x-1)$ (assuming f is monotonically increasing). As it is explicitly stated that it is not strictly monotonic, there must be $a, b \in I$ such that for every $x\in(a, b)$: $a< f(x)=f(x+1)=...<b$ . Therefore, there exists an open sub-interval $(a, b)$ on which $f$ is constant.

"If $f$ is differentiable, such that $f'\geq0$ or $f'\leq0$ on $I$, and $f'$ disappears only a countable number of times, then f is strictly monotonic"

Aside from the fact that I am only assuming that "disappears" means that $f'$ doesn't need to be continuous, I would assume that if the derivative was greater (less) or equal to zero, and not strictly greater (or less), then there would be an $x$ such that $f(x)=f(x+1)$, which would then imply that the monotonicity is not strict. I am aware that a function is monotonic if its first derivative does not change sign, however I don't see how this implies strict monotonicity.

Comment: You seem to think the difference between $f$ at $x$ and at $x+1$ will be helpful. I think that's not a useful idea. Scrap it and a better argument should emerge from things you have said.

Comment: @EthanBolker I am aware that f(x) and f(x+1) doesn't really help the argument when looking at real numbers, but I was just trying to find a way to write that one number is equal to the number that follows it. Do you know a suitable alternative notation or would you make a different approach? Thanks.

Comment: There is no "next number" after a number on the number line. The  mechanism using limits and continuity is what mathematicians have invented to reason rigorously about things you grasp intuitively thinking about the "next number". As the answer you've accepted shows, you don't need that much sophistication here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume $f$ is monotonically increasing.

So we have:

- Monotonically increasing:
  $\forall x,y \in I: x < y \to f(x) \le f(y)$
- Not strictly monotonically increasing:
  $\neg \forall x,y \in I: x < y \to f(x) < f(y)$

  Which can also be written as:
  $\exists x,y \in I: x < y \land f(x) \ge f(y)$

This implies:
$\exists x,y \in I: x < y \land f(x) = f(y)$

Now for any $z \in I$ such that $x < z < y$ we have $f(x) \le f(z) \le f(y)$. And since $f(x) = f(y)$, we have $f(x) = f(y) = f(z)$ and $f$ is constant on interval $(x, y)$.